# PyOmo/Ipopt fails with "can't evaluate pow"

Tags: optimization, ipopt, pyomo

I am using PyOmo to generate a nonlinear model which will ultimately be solved with Ipopt. The model is as follows:

```
from pyomo.environ import *
from pyomo.dae import *

m = ConcreteModel()

m.t = ContinuousSet(bounds=(0,100)) 

m.T  = Param(default=100,mutable=True)
m.a  = Param(default=0.1)
m.kP = Param(default=20)
m.P  = Var(m.t, bounds=(0,None))
m.S  = Var(m.t, bounds=(0,None))
m.u  = Var(m.t, bounds=(0,1), initialize=0.5)

m.Pdot = DerivativeVar(m.P)
m.Sdot = DerivativeVar(m.S)

m.obj = Objective(expr=m.S[100],sense=maximize)

def _Pdot(M,i):
  if i == 0:
    return Constraint.Skip
  return M.Pdot[i] == (1-M.u[i])*(M.P[i]**0.75)

def _Sdot(M,i):
  if i == 0:
    return Constraint.Skip
  return M.Sdot[i] == M.u[i]*0.2*(M.P[i]**0.75)

def _init(M):
  yield M.P[0] == 2
  yield M.S[0] == 0
  yield ConstraintList.End

m.Pdotcon         = Constraint(m.t, rule=_Pdot)
m.Sdotcon         = Constraint(m.t, rule=_Sdot)
m.init_conditions = ConstraintList(rule=_init)

discretizer = TransformationFactory('dae.collocation')
discretizer.apply_to(m,nfe=100,ncp=3,scheme='LAGRANGE-RADAU')
discretizer.reduce_collocation_points(m,var=m.u,ncp=1,contset=m.t)

solver  = SolverFactory('ipopt')
results = solver.solve(m,tee=False)
```

Running the model results in the following error:

```
Error evaluating constraint 1: can't evaluate pow'(0,0.75).

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyomo/opt/base/solvers.py", line 577, in solve
    "Solver (%s) did not exit normally" % self.name)
pyutilib.common._exceptions.ApplicationError: Solver (asl) did not exit normally
```

The first part of the error comes from Ipopt whereas the second part comes from PyOmo. Evidently the issue has something ot do with the term `M.P[i]**0.75` in the constraints, but changing the power does not resolve the issue (though `2.0` did work).

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message states that `pow'(0,0.75)` cannot be evaluated. The `'` character in this function indicates the first derivative (`''` would indiate the second derivative). The message is effectively saying that the first derivative does not exist or results in an infinity at zero.

Resolving the issue is easy: bound your variables to a non-zero value as follows:

```
m.P  = Var(m.t, bounds=(1e-20,None))
m.S  = Var(m.t, bounds=(1e-20,None))
```

Answer (score 3):

I would add to Richard's answer:

you might also need to update the initial value of your variable as ipopt assumes 0 if not specified, so it will evaluate the variable at 0 for the first iteration.

hence:

```
m.P  = Var(m.t, bounds=(1e-20,None), initialize=1e-20)
m.S  = Var(m.t, bounds=(1e-20,None), initialize=1e-20)
```

instead of 1e-20 as initialize you might use a value more relevant to your problem